# Infinite loop with asynchronous callback pattern in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, design-patterns, functional-programming, tail-recursion

Suppose I want to send an asynchronous AJAX request to the server, and when it responds send another request and repeat forever:

```
function sendXHR(url, callback) {
    // Send XMLHttpRequest to server and call callback when response is received
}

function infinite() {
    sendXHR('url/path', infinite);
}

infinite();
```

I assume here we would run out of stack space pretty quickly, so how can I do this (without blocking)?

The pattern of passing callbacks around rather than using `return` is particularly popular with `node.js`. How do people create infinite loops? I don't believe most JS engines do any kind of tail call optimisation.

Comment: That would not run out of stack space as when the callback is called the stack frames below it do not contain the stack of the previous `infinite` call.

Comment: @DanD. I tried it in Chrome by adding `callback();` in `sendXHR`, and it reports `Maximum call stack size exceeded` after around 9500 iterations. Firefox also says `too much recursion`.

Comment: Well then maybe there's something interesting in the *Send XMLHttpRequest to server and call callback when response is received* part.

Comment: @muistooshort Sorry don't follow, am I missing something obvious?

Comment: I'm guessing your `sendXHR` function is using synchronous xhr then? Change this to asynchronous and execute the callback on the next tick.

Comment: We don't know what `sendXHR` actually does.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If your ajax call is asynchronous, you do not run out of stack space because `sendXHR()` returns immediately after the ajax request is sent.  The callback is then called some time later when the ajax response arrives.  There is no stack build up.

---

If your ajax call is synchronous and you want to allow other events and what not to happen in the javascript environment, then you could so something like this:

```
function sendXHR(url, callback) {
    // Send XMLHttpRequest to server and call callback when response is received
}

function infinite() {
    sendXHR('url/path');
    setTimeout(infinite, 1);
}

infinite();
```

Comment: His comments seem to prove that he does indeed run out of stack space, so it looks like he's sing synchronous XHR.

Comment: @SeanKinsey - since the OP was not clear about synch vs. async, I've now included answers for both.

Comment: Thanks, you are of course right.. there is no stack build up if it's asynchronous.